# Cannot choose the name for a png image in OSM (python)

Tags: python, png, openstreetmap

I am trying to save a path built with OSM as a png image but I don't know how to put the name given by this function (which is the filename):

```
def plot_directions(graph, source_location, destination_location, directions, filename, width=400, height=400):
    ...
    image.save("filename.png")
```

The filename is something like `filename = "city"`
I know that this approach is not correct for my purpose. How can I do it?
Thanks

Comment: So your code does not work? What is the error? [Edit] this into your question; telling us what the actual results are, is as important as expected results in helping you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the method parameter '**fileName**' is the name of the file, such as `fileName = "image.png"`,
You can simply call this:

```
 image.save(filename)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Now I realize I should have said that the file names are something like `filename = "city"`.  So that is why I am struggling with this matter.

Comment: Great. I'm glad to be of help.
Now could you please mark this as an answer?

Comment: Sorry I am still struggling with this matter as the filename is something like "city" without the png ending.
So I still don't know how to make it work with a non png ending name. Because when I put `image.save(filename)` it raises an error

Comment: Then how about doing this:
image.save(filename+'.png')

Comment: Thanks a lot I haven't thought about it I had to define file = filename+png before doing image.save(file). And it worked.